# Why sin/cos are slower when optimizations are enabled?

Tags: c++, performance

After reading a question related with the performance of sin/cos ([Why is std::sin() and std::cos() slower than sin() and cos()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976458/why-is-stdsin-and-stdcos-slower-than-sin-and-cos)), I made some tests with his code and found a weird thing: If i call sin/cos with a float value, it is much slower than with double when compiled with optimization.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

const int N = 4000;

float cosine[N][N];
float sine[N][N];

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            float ang = i*j*2*M_PI/N;
            cosine[i][j] = cos(ang);
            sine[i][j] = sin(ang);
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code I get:

With -O0: 2.402s

With -O1: 9.004s

With -O2: 9.013s

With -O3: 9.001s

Now if I change

```
float ang = i*j*2*M_PI/N;
```

To

```
double ang = i*j*2*M_PI/N;
```

I get:

With -O0: 2.362s

With -O1: 1.188s

With -O2: 1.197s

With -O3: 1.197s

How can the first test be that faster without optimizations?

I'm using g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2, 64 bits.

**EDIT:** Changed the title to better describe the problem.

**EDIT:** Added assembly code

Assembly for first test with O0:

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
.globl cosine
    .bss
    .align 32
    .type   cosine, @object
    .size   cosine, 64000000
cosine:
    .zero   64000000
.globl sine
    .align 32
    .type   sine, @object
    .size   sine, 64000000
sine:
    .zero   64000000
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB87:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L2
.L5:
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
    jmp .L3
.L4:
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    imull   -8(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %eax, %eax
    cvtsi2sd    %eax, %xmm0
    movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm1
    mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm1
    divsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    unpcklpd    %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvtpd2ps    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movss   %xmm0, -12(%rbp)
    movss   -12(%rbp), %xmm0
    cvtps2pd    %xmm0, %xmm0
    call    cos
    unpcklpd    %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvtpd2ps    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
    movslq  %edx, %rdx
    imulq   $4000, %rdx, %rdx
    leaq    (%rdx,%rax), %rax
    movss   %xmm0, cosine(,%rax,4)
    movss   -12(%rbp), %xmm0
    cvtps2pd    %xmm0, %xmm0
    call    sin
    unpcklpd    %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvtpd2ps    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    cltq
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
    movslq  %edx, %rdx
    imulq   $4000, %rdx, %rdx
    leaq    (%rdx,%rax), %rax
    movss   %xmm0, sine(,%rax,4)
    addl    $1, -8(%rbp)
.L3:
    cmpl    $3999, -8(%rbp)
    setle   %al
    testb   %al, %al
    jne .L4
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L2:
    cmpl    $3999, -4(%rbp)
    setle   %al
    testb   %al, %al
    jne .L5
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE87:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .rodata
    .align 4
    .type   _ZL1N, @object
    .size   _ZL1N, 4
_ZL1N:
    .long   4000
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .long   1413754136
    .long   1074340347
    .align 8
.LC1:
    .long   0
    .long   1085227008
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Assembly for first test with O3:

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB121:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %r15
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    xorl    %r15d, %r15d
    .cfi_offset 15, -16
    pushq   %r14
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    movl    $cosine+16000, %r14d
    .cfi_offset 14, -24
    pushq   %r13
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    xorl    %r13d, %r13d
    .cfi_offset 13, -32
    pushq   %r12
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 40
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
    pushq   %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 56
    subq    $24, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 80
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L2:
    movslq  %r15d, %rbp
    .cfi_offset 3, -56
    .cfi_offset 6, -48
    .cfi_offset 12, -40
    movl    %r13d, %r12d
    movl    $0x3f800000, %edx
    imulq   $16000, %rbp, %rbp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leaq    cosine(%rbp), %rbx
    addq    $sine, %rbp
    jmp .L5
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L3:
    movl    %r12d, %eax
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rsi
    leaq    12(%rsp), %rdi
    subl    %r13d, %eax
    cvtsi2sd    %eax, %xmm0
    mulsd   .LC2(%rip), %xmm0
    divsd   .LC3(%rip), %xmm0
    unpcklpd    %xmm0, %xmm0
    cvtpd2ps    %xmm0, %xmm0
    call    sincosf
    movl    8(%rsp), %edx
    movl    12(%rsp), %eax
.L5:
    movl    %edx, (%rbx)
    addq    $4, %rbx
    movl    %eax, 0(%rbp)
    addl    %r13d, %r12d
    addq    $4, %rbp
    cmpq    %r14, %rbx
    jne .L3
    addl    $1, %r15d
    addl    $2, %r13d
    leaq    16000(%rbx), %r14
    cmpl    $4000, %r15d
    jne .L2
    addq    $24, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 56
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 40
    popq    %r12
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    popq    %r13
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
    popq    %r14
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    popq    %r15
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE121:
    .size   main, .-main
.globl cosine
    .bss
    .align 32
    .type   cosine, @object
    .size   cosine, 64000000
cosine:
    .zero   64000000
.globl sine
    .align 32
    .type   sine, @object
    .size   sine, 64000000
sine:
    .zero   64000000
    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align 8
.LC2:
    .long   1413754136
    .long   1074340347
    .align 8
.LC3:
    .long   0
    .long   1085227008
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if you provided the generated assembly code for each case. Use the `-S` option to gcc to create an assembly listing.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Added assembly code to the question.

Comment: @fbafelipe: Well something obvious is that the compiler is using `xmm1` with -O0, but not with -O3. Beats me as to why, though...

Comment: I got surprising results today with your small benchmark code and experimenting with the functions ::sin, ::sinf, std::sin, sincos, sincosf. Depending on Processor (ARM64 vs AMD64) and compiler flags (-O0 vs -O3, -ffast-math or not) the runtime varied greatly (factor 2 to 5) between comparable versions. Short conclusion: Measure!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

In C, `cos` is double precision and `cosf` is single precision.  In C++, `std::cos` has overloads for both double and single.

You aren't calling `std::cos`.  If `<cmath>` doesn't also overload `::cos` (as far as I know, it is not required to), then you are just calling the C double precision function.  If this is the case, then you're suffering the cost of converting between float, double, and back.

Now, some standard libraries implement `cos(float x)` as `(float)cos((double)x)`, so even if you are calling the `float` function it might still be doing conversions behind the scenes.

This shouldn't account for a 9x performance difference, though.

Comment: I changed the calls to cosf and sinf, with O0 it gone to 17.198s and with O3 it was the same (8.999s). Checking the assembly I posted in the question, it shows a call to sincosf (instead of sincos - note that it used a function that compute sin and cos at the same time). So it seems that with optimization the compiler decided to change to a slower fuction instead of doing the cast...

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/FP-Function-Optimizations.html - does using __NO_MATH_INLINES remove this behaviour?

Comment: @andrew cooke: No, same results with or without __NO_MATH_INLINES.

Comment: The conversions between `float` and `double` do not account for it. I ran some tests today with g++ and found that when using `-O2` the `float` code was much slower. However, when I tested with manual conversions, like this: `(float)sin((double)input)` I found that the optimized `float` code ran _faster_ than the optimized `double` code, even though I was forcing the `float` code to use the `double` `sin` function.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it's because computers work at double precision natively. Using float requires conversions.'

Comment: But why it's faster with -O0 than with -O3? This performance problem only happen when optimization is enabled.

Comment: @fbafelipe : Optimizing for size? That would make the most sense. Usually size comes at a cost.

Comment: @fbafelipe: The only way to answer that question is to disassemble the compiled program with and without optimizations, as was done in the question you linked to.

Comment: @Ethan: But -Os is for size optimization; -O3 is supposed to be speed at the cost of size, with (for example) inlining.