# Using the x87-FPU in x64/AMD64-mode under Linux

Tags: linux, x87

Does anyone know whether Linux supports the use of the x87-FPU in 64-bit-mode, i.e. if the instructions are not trapped and the registers are saved on context-switch. I don't want to use it and I know SSE is the standard in x64-mode; it's just for curiosity.

Comment: Have you tried it? What research did you make? Did you compile a program with `gcc` to find out it uses x87 instructions? Or others? What instructions do you think "linux" uses on processors that do not support SSE, but support x87? According to a short read about [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Math_Optimization_Flags), you can use `-mfpmath=387` with `gcc`. There is some info [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is supported. The D language uses that feature. When you use the types `float` or `double` it compiles SSE code, when you use `real` which tells the compiler to use the implementations most precise type. In case of x86 it is x87 with its 80 bit type.

https://godbolt.org/z/50kr-H

```
real square(real num) {
    return num * num;
}

float square(float num) {
    return num * num;
}
```

compiles to

```
real example.square(real):
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    fld     tbyte ptr [rbp + 16]
    fstp    tbyte ptr [rbp - 16]
    fld     tbyte ptr [rbp - 16]
    fmul    st(0), st
    pop     rbp
    ret

float example.square(float):
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    movss   dword ptr [rbp - 4], xmm0
    movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rbp - 4]
    mulss   xmm0, dword ptr [rbp - 4]
    pop     rbp
    ret
```